# how to analyze the logic of func RANGE in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am still confused those sentence after I run them, I mean how do they execute step by step, someone can give some suggestions?

```
print([j for i in range (10) for j in range (5)])
print([[j for i in range (10)] for j in range (5)])
print([j for i in range (10) for j in range (5) for k in range(3)])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Largely, list comprehensions are concise for loops. Sometimes they can be difficult to understand and for that reason, I would suggest converting the list comprehension into a for loop for understanding.

```
print([j for i in range(10) for j in range(5)])
```

Is the same as:

```
result = []
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(5):
        result.append(j)
```

The others are very similar, can you try and convert them to for loops?

Hint (2): The second one has a nested list, so you'll need to initialize another list and append that list to the main list, `result`.

Hint (3): The last list comprehension has another nested for loop with another variable `k`.